# Server.MapPath() with IIS URL Rewrite Module 2.0

Tags: iis, asp-classic, url-rewriting, server.mappath

I have a website in IIS, with a legacy classic asp application configured as a sub app.

I'm basically trying to create URL rewrite rules so that I don't have to change all of the relative URL's in the code.

e.g. URLS's such as "*/themes/somedirectory*" should be mapped to "*/legacy/themes/somedirectory*"

Using the [URL Rewrite Module 2.0](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-url-rewrite-module-20) I have a URL rewrite rule configured as follows:

```
<rule name="Reroute themes">
    <match url="^themes.*" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="/legacy/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This works fine when navigating to the URL. However when using `Server.MapPath()`, it is not applying the rewrite rule.

Is `Server.MapPath()` actually supposed to take this into account? If not, how should I go about re-routing the application without modifying the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had this problem, and for now am going with create a special MapPath variant that corresponds to my rewrite rule.

So either something like this:

```
string MapTheme(string themeName)
{
    return Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/legacy"), themeName)
}
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
string MapThemePath(string themeUrl)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match("^themes/(.*)");
    if (!m.Success)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    string themeName = m.Groups[1].Value;
    return Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/legacy"), themeName)
}
```

Or generalize:

```
string MyMapPath(string url)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match("^themes/(.*)");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        string themeName = m.Groups[1].Value;
        return Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("/legacy"), themeName)
    }
    else if (itsAnotherSpecialRewriteCase)
    {
        return doSomeSimilarTransformation();
    }
    // ...
    else
    {
        // Handle non-rewritten URLs
        return Server.MapPath(url);
    }
}
```

I don't especially like this, because it violates "do not repeat yourself".

Comment: We ended up doing something similar, routing all MapPaths to a wrapper that performed the necessary redirections.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same thing so I gave it a try in a test app. It appears that `Server.MapPath()` **does not acknowledge** URL Rewrite Module rules.

Here is how I tested using an empty web project (Razor syntax):

Rewrite rule:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rewrite rule1 for test1">
                <match url="^test1(.*)" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

cshtml:

```
<p>
    The URL for this page is @Request.Url.AbsoluteUri .
    <br />
    MapPath of /test1 is @Server.MapPath("~/test1")
    <br />
    MapPath of / is @Server.MapPath("~/")
</p>
```

I hit `http://localhost/`, then `http://localhost/test1`. The results were:

```
The URL for this page is http://localhost/ .
MapPath of /test1 is c:\src\temp\test1
MapPath of / is c:\src\temp\
```

So looks like mappath is basically taking `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` (or something similar) and combining it with the relative URL. On a side note, I have separately confirmed that `MapPath()` takes into account 1 level of virtual directory, but not a 2nd (ie. virt pointing to another location that also has a virt defined).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Have you come up with a solution that would answer the second part of my question?